# The Prime Explosion: A Visualization of Prime Numbers.

Tags: prime-numbers

Recently wrote this [python demo](https://trinket.io/python3/1bfeffdf8c) to show a prime explosion occurring at the origin. Each radiating line represents a prime number, with its length corresponding to the prime's value. The direction each prime takes is random, resulting in a unique pattern of primes shooting out from the origin.

Example of the first $42$ prime numbers
[image: 42]

Example of the first $4200$ prime numbers
[image: 4200]

**Question**

Apart from its beauty, is there any mathematical significance or value in visualizing primes in this manner?

Comment: We already know that primes get larger as they get bigger, and the arrangement and coloring is random, so no?

Comment: I doubt it. If your visualization showed the density of primes in the vicinity of each radius it might suggest the prime number theorem.

Comment: I guess if there were huge gaps in primes you could see it in various radii gaps, but that would only be anecdotal and nothing helpful in making conjectures.

Comment: Such pictures are also used in the big bang theory to "visualize" the big bang. Nice idea with the "prime explosion" , but yet every pattern that has been discovered vanished for larger primes and I am pretty sure this is no exception.